# Big .las to raster converting by writers.gdal

Tags: python, las, point-cloud, pdal, bigtiff

I have a script:

```
pipeline = [
path,
{
    "filename": out_path,
    "gdaldriver": "GTiff",
    "resolution": 1,
    "output_type": "max",
    "type": "writers.gdal",
    "data_type": "float32",
}
]
pipeline = pdal.Pipeline(json.dumps(pipeline))
pipeline.validate()
pipeline.execute()
```

it converts .las file into .tif. The problem occurs with big (>1,5Gb) files: the output is a black square with dimension 1x1. What should I do to process big .las succesfully?